# how to share context between two functional components which will render in different createNodes ? need to invoke this code in my existing js app

Tags: reactjs, react-context

#### Accesing state in <annotation> is not same as <chat>.

can't use redux here , quiet a small app so i ignored it.
what changes can i do in context.js to achiche this is functionality

index.js

```
import { AppContext,AppContextProvider } from "./context";
const BookBot = (props) => {
    const botRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById((props?.toolbox)))
    const botAnnot = createRoot(document.getElementById((props?.annotbox)))
    botRoot.render(
        <AppContextProvider>
            <Chat />
        </AppContextProvider>
    );
    botAnnot.render(
        <AppContextProvider>
            <Annotaion />
        </AppContextProvider>
    )
}
```

contex.js

```
const AppContext = React.createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    chats:[],
    query:undefined,
    sendDisabled:false,
    chatId:""
  });
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this using zustand.

[zustand : creates a global store](https://zustand-demo.pmnd.rs/)

context.js

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
const useGlobalStore = create((setState) => ({
  chats:[],
  query:undefined,
  sendDisabled:false,
  chatId:"",
  setState : setState

}))
export default useGlobalStore;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want `<Chat/>` and `<Annotation/>` to share a context, you must put a single provider higher up the tree that they are both child components of.  example:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider>
            <Chat/>
            <Annotation/>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

unlike Redux, which is global, createContext/useContext pull from the next higher-up provider.
from the docs:

> useContext returns the context value for the calling component. **It is determined as the value passed to the closest SomeContext.Provider above the calling component in the tree.** If there is no such provider, then the returned value will be the defaultValue you have passed to createContext for that context. The returned value is always up-to-date. React automatically re-renders components that read some context if it changes.

https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

so in your situation, you have two separate providers handling their own state, not sharing a single provider.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. 
This could work , If i could render paranetComponent using single render Statement, where as i have to render both chat and annotation in separate places.
Let me know if am missing something here.

Comment: glad you found a solution.  just so you understand your options, you don't actually have to render both components directly under the context provider.  they could be separately rendered as long there was a single closest provider instance somewhere above them.  it could even technically be up at the App level if you wanted a "global" provider.

Comment: Can you please share an example snippet for the same, that will be helpful for my understanding.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a5kmdpb2/
obviously i don't know the structure of your app, so i doubt that fiddle is very helpful.  but all i'm trying to say is that the child components can be separately rendered anywhere in the tree and they can still share a context provider as long at it exists somewhere above both of them.  don't think you are limited to rendering them together in order to share a context.  cheers!